# Change 5 GHz Wi-Fi Access Point channel

Tags: wi-fi

Is it possible to set or change the channel of the Android Wi-Fi AP?
No matter it is using root or non root methods.

I'm currently on Android 10.

Comment: Xiaomi Mi 8. But I have this problem in different ROMs, that's why I just said Android 10, happening both in MIUI and AOSP.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible because that needs to be done at the router end by configuration. Nothing at device end to change channels //If your device is rooted, you can enable /disable  5Ghz using Magisk modules